# How to find all statements which a failed transaction executed in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-deadlocks

We are encountering a lot of deadlocks, and while we found out that the problematic Foreign Key, we could not understand why exactly it happened.

I looked into the performance_schema tables to understand but I dont think I have sufficient knowledge. Here's what I thought would help me debug deadlock:

1. Look into the transation ID/Thread ID of the two conflicting transactions (available from output of Show Engine innodb status)
2. I want to see all the statements for the two transaction, after one has failed and one has succeeded. Is that even possible?
3. Once I have that info, I can get more clarity, and hopefully pinpoint why the deadlock happened

I was focusing on events_statements_history_long, but with the Thread ID I got in step 1, I got no rows in response withing a minute of deadlock.

Is this the correct approach? If not, where I'm going wrong? If yet, Is there relevant literature out there which can give more clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output of `Show Engine innodb status` as you said.
The latest deadlock information section will show you the two statements that caused the latest deadlock in the system.
If you are encountering many different deadlocks, you may want to enable `innodb_print_all_deadlocks` to view them in the mysqld error log.

You will be able to see the statements and lock types on which table that resulted in a deadlock.

Comment: I doubt if it prints all the "statement"? Can you please let me know how the sample output would look like?

Comment: I am specifically looking for the SQL statements in the transaction which led to the deadlock.